# Yocto OS set the KeyboardLayout

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

Hy I wanted to change the keyboard layout in my image. I wanted to have a German layout.

for this I tried to set the local.conf:

```
KEYBOARD_LAYOUT = "de"
```

I also tried to add this:

```
LOCALE_FLAGS:append = " de_DE.utf8"
```

I get no error when I build the image but when I start it it is English. I am building the core-image-base for the raspberry 4.

I wrote the logs like this:
bitbake -e "image name" >/tmp/filedump
In ther i can see that my configuration got seleced:

```
# $LOCALE_Flags
#   _append /home/parallels/yocto/build/conf/local.conf:58
#     " de_DE.utf8"
LOCALE_Flags=" de_DE.utf8"

# $KEYBOARD_LAYOUT
#   set /home/parallels/yocto/build/conf/local.conf:59
#     "de"
KEYBOARD_LAYOUT="de"
```